# What matters should I care to make my theme SEO friendly?

Tags: theme-development, seo

I want to know all the things that I should care for a well SEO optimizations for my theme.
What options should I provide to users for SEO optimizations?

Please suggest all the things those you know with a short brief.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Here you find a ton informations about SEO (and they in the most article shares wordpress plugins also): https://www.searchenginejournal.com/

Comment: Otherwise the base of onsite SEO that, you need use <h{1,2, etc.}> tags in your site, nofollow rel on the exetrnal links AND also very important that, you need SSL certification (--> Cloudflare have totally free wildcard SSL)... Check these plugins: wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/, https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/

Comment: I actually don't know why peoples are giving downvotes to this question. Can anyone explain to me the reason, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The theme you are going to made has to be developed according to up-to-date coding standards and can be validate : https://validator.w3.org/
- You need to use semantic tags : https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_semantic_elements.asp